# Android - Determinate ProgressDialog inside DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I know that Google's Material Design guidelines don't recommend using a ProgressDialog, instead using another less intrusive way to display progress, but I need to use a ProgressDialog for a specific Activity of my app.

So, the thing is that I want to wrap a ProgressDialog inside a DialogFragment, and thus my code is as follows:

```
public class MaterialProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private int total;
private MaterialDialog myDialog;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return myDialog;
}

public void incrementProgress(int by) {
    myDialog.incrementProgress(by);
}

public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public void setUp(Context context) {
    myDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
            .title("Progress")
            .content("Processing...")
            .progress(false, total, true)
            .build();
}
```

}

Because what I want to build is a determinate ProgressDialog, I want to be able to update its progress throghout the life of my app. For this I have made a method called setProgress(progress), but myDialog is always null, as well as the value returned from getDialog().

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

EDIT: I'm showing the dialog inside my fragment's onCreateActivity() method, like follows:

```
MaterialProgressDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MaterialProgressDialogFragment();
dialogFragment.setTotal(100);
dialogFragment.setUp(getActivity());
dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
dialog.incrementProgress(50);
```

Everything works as expected until the last line, which causes the app to throw an exception.

Comment: Post the code where you start this dialog. Do you invoke setProgress after you show the dialog?

Comment: @Simas It's now posted

Comment: There are various references to a member called `dialog`, but you are not showing anywhere what it is and how it's initialised.

Comment: Your code is still showing an instance called `dialog` that is neither declared nor initialised anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't totally clear what the variable `dialog` inside `setProgress(int progress)` method is. But if you mean `getDialog()` by that, it takes time to create dialog by dialog fragment, and between the `dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "")` and `onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)` callback there will be some time interval, during which `getDialog()` will return `null`.

EDIT:
Ok, now it is more clear. But by the code above, you're violating the fragment framework rules. You should create your dialog in `onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, because otherwise you'll have problems with lifecycle (for example, if you'll rotate your screen, the app will crash).

I suggest you to use something like that:

```
public class MaterialProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TOTAL_KEY = "total";

    public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(int total) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TOTAL_KEY, total);
        ProgressDialogFragment pdf = new ProgressDialogFragment();
        pdf.setArguments(args);
        return pdf;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MaterialDialog myDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                .title("Progress")
                .content("Processing...")
                .progress(false, getTotal(), true)
                .build();
        return myDialog;
    }

    public void incrementProgress(int by) {
        if (getDialog()!=null)
            ((MaterialDialog)getDialog()).incrementProgress(by);
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return getArguments().getInt(TOTAL_KEY);
    }
}
```

You should save `total` variable to arguments, because it will be destroyed on configuration change (for example screen rotation).

Then just create and show it by:

```
MaterialProgressDialogFragment dialogFragment = MaterialProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(100);
dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
```

When you want to change your progress, call:

```
dialog.incrementProgress(50);
```

But remember, dialog won't be created immediately, so if you'll call this right after show(), it won't take effect, because `getDialog()` will return null. If you want to just test it, call it delayed:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.incrementProgress(50);
            }
        }, 200);
```

But anyway in real app you will change your progress from some background process.

Comment: For dialog I meant myDialog